# Java BinaryTree: How to balance a tree in the insert method?

Tags: java, avl-tree, tree-balancing

I am trying to get a binary search tree to balance, and I know why it's not working, but I don't know how to fix it.
I balance directly in the insert method.
I put some slash to note where the balancing should happen.
Like this the code is not working and i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Baueme.Treee.insert(Treee.java:54)
at Baueme.Treee.insert(Treee.java:18)
at Baueme.TestTheTree.main(TestTheTree.java:12)
```

When I insert without the balancing everthing is fine.

```
public class Node {

public Node left, right, parent;
public int value;

public Node (Node parent, int i) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = i;
}

public int height() {
    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;

    if (this.left  != null) {
        l = this.left.height() +1;
    }

    if (this.right  != null) {
        r = this.right.height() +1;
    }

    return Math.max(l,r);
}   
}
public class Tree {
Node root;

public Tree() {
    root = null;
}

public void insert (int value) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(null, value);
    }
    else {
        insert(root, value);
    }
}

private void insert (Node parent, int value) {

    if (parent.value >= value) {

        if (parent.left == null) {
            parent.left = new Node (parent, value);
        }
        else {
            insert(parent.left, value);

       /////////////////////////    
            if ( parent.left.height() - parent.right.height() == 2) {

                if (value - parent.left.value < 0) {
                    parent = rotateWithLeftChild(parent);
                }
                else {
                    parent = doubleRotateWithRightChild(parent);
                }
            }           
      /////////////////////////
        }
    }

    else {

        if (parent.right == null) {
            parent.right = new Node (parent, value);
        }
        else {
            insert(parent.right, value);
      /////////////////////////
            if ( parent.left.height() - parent.right.height() == -2) {

                if (value - parent.right.value > 0) {
                    parent = rotateWithRightChild(parent);
                }
                else {
                    parent = doubleRotateWithLeftChild(parent);
                }
            }
     /////////////////////////
    }
     }
     }
    public int quantity() {

if (root == null) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1 + quantity(root.left) + quantity(root.right);          
}
 }
public int quantity (Node parent) {

if (parent == null) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1 + quantity(parent.left) + quantity(parent.right);
}
}
public int height () {

int l = 0;
int r = 0;

if ( root.left != null) {
    l = height(root.left) + 1;
}

if (root.right != null) {
    r = height(root.right) +1;
}

return (Math.max(l,r));
}
private int height (Node parent) {

int l = 0;
int r = 0;

if ( parent.left != null) {
    l = height(parent.left) + 1;
}

if (parent.right != null)   {
    r = height(parent.right) +1;
}

return (Math.max(l,r));
}
public String toString () {

    if (root == null) {
        return "empty tree";
    }
    else {
        return toString(root.left) + " ; " + root.value + " ; " +  toString(root.right);
    }
}


private String toString (Node parent) {

    if (parent == null) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return toString(parent.left) + " ; " + parent.value
        + " ; " + toString(parent.right);
    }
}
private String toString (Node parent) {

if (parent == null) {
    return "";
}
else {
    return toString(parent.left) + " ; " + parent.value
    + " ; " +     toString(parent.right);
  }
 }
private Node rotateWithLeftChild (Node k2) {
Node k1 = k2.left;
k2.left = k1.right;
k1.right = k2;

return k1;
}
private Node rotateWithRightChild (Node k1) {
Node k2 = k1.right;
k1.right = k2.left;
k2.left = k1;

return k2;
}
private Node doubleRotateWithRightChild (Node k3) {
k3.left = rotateWithRightChild(k3.left);

return rotateWithLeftChild(k3);
}
private Node doubleRotateWithLeftChild (Node k1) {
k1.right = rotateWithLeftChild(k1.right);
return rotateWithRightChild(k1);
}

}
public class TestTheTree {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Treee temp = new Treee();

    temp.insert(10);
    temp.insert(20);
    temp.insert(30);


    System.out.println(temp.toString());


  }
  }
```

Comment: Which line is line 54?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @immibis line 54 is this:       if ( parent.left.height() - parent.right.height() == -2) {  ..it is in the insert method.

Comment: @member555 yes it is a AVL tree.

Comment: you are accessing to Null nodes

Comment: yes, because the NullPointer .. but should be possible to balance at that point?

Comment: parent.right is null.

Comment: You should really format that code as if you were handing it in for review by your professor or supervisor. I'm not going to bother with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing a null node. The third node (with a value of 30) is inserted without any issues, however at that point only right children exist in the tree (you added a node with a value of 10, which becomes the root, then you added a node with a value of 20, which becomes the right child of the root, and then you add a node with a value of 30, which becomes the right child of the node with a value of 20).

Therefore, since there are only right children, when you try to access parent.left it will be null. So, when you try to balance the tree, you should add some logic to ensure that parent.left and parent.right are not null. I added some code to the Tree.java file to get you started. However, it looks as thought you will probably have some additional problems to deal with, since in line 67 of the code that I pasted below you try to access 'parent.right.value' without any code to ensure that 'parent.right' is not null. I also left the print statements that I used to debug your code to help you debug it yourself.

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;

    public Tree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void insert (int value) {

        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(null, value);
        }
        else {
            insert(root, value);
        }
    }

    private void insert (Node parent, int value) {

        if (parent.value >= value) {

            if (parent.left == null) {
                parent.left = new Node (parent, value);
            }
            else {
                insert(parent.left, value);

           /////////////////////////    
                if ( parent.left.height() - parent.right.height() == 2) {

                    if (value - parent.left.value < 0) {
                        parent = rotateWithLeftChild(parent);
                    }
                    else {
                        parent = doubleRotateWithRightChild(parent);
                    }
                }           
          /////////////////////////
            }
        }

        else {

            if (parent.right == null) {
                parent.right = new Node (parent, value);
                System.out.println("Node inserted as a right child.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("We are in the insert method, before the recursive call");
                insert(parent.right, value);
                System.out.println("We are in the insert method, after the recursive call");
          /////////////////////////
                System.out.println("parent" + parent);
                System.out.println("parent.value " + parent.value);
                System.out.println("parent.left " + parent.left);
                System.out.println("parent.right " + parent.right);
                int leftHeight = 0;
                int rightHeight = 0;
                if( parent.left != null )
                    leftHeight = parent.left.height();

                if( parent.right != null )
                    rightHeight = parent.right.height();

                if ( leftHeight - rightHeight == -2) {

                    if (value - parent.right.value > 0) {
                        parent = rotateWithRightChild(parent);
                    }
                    else {
                        parent = doubleRotateWithLeftChild(parent);
                    }
                }
         /////////////////////////
        }
         }
         }
        public int quantity() {

    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + quantity(root.left) + quantity(root.right);          
    }
     }
    public int quantity (Node parent) {

    if (parent == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + quantity(parent.left) + quantity(parent.right);
    }
    }
    public int height () {

    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;

    if ( root.left != null) {
        l = height(root.left) + 1;
    }

    if (root.right != null) {
        r = height(root.right) +1;
    }

    return (Math.max(l,r));
    }
    private int height (Node parent) {

    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;

    if ( parent.left != null) {
        l = height(parent.left) + 1;
    }

    if (parent.right != null)   {
        r = height(parent.right) +1;
    }

    return (Math.max(l,r));
    }
    public String toString () {

        if (root == null) {
            return "empty tree";
        }
        else {
            return toString(root.left) + " ; " + root.value + " ; " +  toString(root.right);
        }
    }

    private String toString (Node parent) {

    if (parent == null) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return toString(parent.left) + " ; " + parent.value
        + " ; " +     toString(parent.right);
      }
     }
    private Node rotateWithLeftChild (Node k2) {
    Node k1 = k2.left;
    k2.left = k1.right;
    k1.right = k2;

    return k1;
    }
    private Node rotateWithRightChild (Node k1) {
    Node k2 = k1.right;
    k1.right = k2.left;
    k2.left = k1;

    return k2;
    }
    private Node doubleRotateWithRightChild (Node k3) {
    k3.left = rotateWithRightChild(k3.left);

    return rotateWithLeftChild(k3);
    }
    private Node doubleRotateWithLeftChild (Node k1) {
    k1.right = rotateWithLeftChild(k1.right);
    return rotateWithRightChild(k1);
    }

}
```